# Stata "invalid name" error

Tags: stata

I am trying to run this code:

```
gen ttt = tt + 123;

tsset ttt, quarterly;

gen lOE = ln(OE);

gen grOE = lOE - L.lOE;
```

I keep getting an error saying 123 is a "invalid name". Could someone explain why this is happening and how I could fix it. I am very new to Stata so I have no idea. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I can't reproduce that.

```
clear 
set obs 1 
gen tt = 1 
#delimit ; 
gen ttt = tt + 123; 
#delimit cr 

list 

     +----------+
     | tt   ttt |
     |----------|
  1. |  1   124 |
     +----------+
```

Please give a reproducible example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: # delimit ;

drop _all;

set more on;

infile tt OE OUR OER AE AUR AER using
"/Users/blank/Desktop/Data/LF Real Stata.dta";

gen ttt = tt + 121;

tsset ttt, quarterly;

gen lOE = ln(OE);

gen grOE = lOE - L.lOE;

Comment: How can that be a reproducible example when it depends on a file on your machine? Success in getting answers in a programming forum depends on asking questions that can be answered. Please study the linked web page. Conversely, what happens if you try the code in my answer?

Answer (score 0):

```
infile tt OE OUR OER AE AUR AER using "/Users/blank/Desktop/Data/LF Real Stata.dta"
```

As `help infile` explains, your infile command is intended to for importing into Stata unformatted text data. But the filename you specify suggests that the file contains a Stata dataset. Perhaps you meant

```
use tt OE OUR OER AE AUR AER using "/Users/blank/Desktop/Data/LF Real Stata.dta"
```